# Is there any PaaS cloud service provider that do not have their own offsite data center?

Tags: cloud, backup, paas, offsite

I have worry about that the PaaS does not have their own offsite data centre for backup our data. Is there any information about how many PaaS do not have a offsite for backup the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find this kind of information directly on a website. Best is to look for the info provider by provider.

A simple Google search with the key words: "provider" backup policy will bring you this info. I just got the CloudBees one in the first position. Same with the other providers.

Comment: I have searched it on Google, but the PaaS do not mention that they have no offsite data centre directly.

Comment: AFAIF providers don't usually have their own offsite datacenter. They usually use high-level providers like Amazon as infrastructure. If they usually use IaaS as Amazon or others, I don't think they will invest in infrastructure for this purpose.

However, I think this is good since it will be very difficult to get a better service like Amazon could provide you.